# Getting "string expected" error when using the TIDES package

Tags: string-manipulation, packages

TIDES is a package that approximates ODEs using a Taylor series method (You can download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tidesodes/ ).

First I call the package:

```
<< MathTIDES
```

Then I introduce the ODE:

```
sincosODE = FirstOrderODE[{y, -x}, t, {x, y}];
```

Then the command `TSMCodeFiles` supposedly should return archives .c to compile:

```
TSMCodeFiles[
  sincosODE,
  "sincosMFL",
  InitialConditions -> {0, 1},
  IntegrationPoints -> {0, Pi/2, Points[1]},
  Output -> Screen,
  MinTIDES -> "C"]
```

But the output of this line returns the error:

> StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in This file has been created by MathTIDES (<>mathTIDESVersion\$<>) . >>
>   String expected at position 2 in This file has been created by MathTIDES (<>mathTIDESVersion$<>) June 4, . >>

Files "dr_sincosMCL.c", "sincosMCL.c",  written in the directory

It seems that these string errors are in the .c files. So How can I fix them when it's the package that created them?

Comment: From the error it would seem that a Symbol `mathTIDESVersion$` does not have an assigned String value.  Yet in the `/MathTIDES/init.m` file the line `mathTIDESVersion$ = "2.00"` should define this.  Therefore I think somehow the package is not being loaded properly.  Nevertheless what happens if you manually set `mathTIDESVersion$ = "2.00"` before evaluating your `TSMCodeFiles` expression?

Comment: With that line it seems everything works.

Comment: That's great!  I think something is still wrong, either with the package itself or the way it is loaded, as that *should* have been set on initialization.  Nevertheless I am glad I could help.

Comment: @CarlosVázquezMonzón Would you mind summarizing your experience and Mr. Wizard's suggestion in a self-answer? This may be helpful for other people suffering from the same issue.